# FILL_PARENT for DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

If I'm using Dialog then Dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

But I need to use DialogFragment.

[image: I want]

Comment: you want a full screen dialog?

Comment: have you tried `DialogFragment`.? or seen any sample.?

Comment: @dr_yand what is the problem question is not clear

Comment: Then who said not to use DialogFragment, you can :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a answer.
Need to add to the DialogFragment:

```
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);       
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use an Activity with Dialog Theme. It will take care of orientation and other things.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Just use

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);`
```

in your `onCreate` Method.